# How to convert "\\u0301" to "\u0301"

Tags: string, go, unicode, unicode-escapes

The problem that I met is that
Given a string contains several special substrings like:
`"\\u0301" "\\b" "\\t"`,..etc

Please convert all special strings above into `"\u0301","\b","\t"`, ..etc

Note that if just removing a backslash here,
you will get a plaintext of `"\u0301"`,
instead an accent mark of Unicode.

A one-by-one solution is to replace each special string

```golang
str = strings.Replace(str, "\\u0301","\u0301", -1)
```

Is a general solution to all escape character codes?

Comment: What format the original string is encoded in? There is a chance there is a proper decoder for it, so that you didn't need to mess with string replace functions.

Comment: Use package strconv after studing the documentation and understanding how string literals work in Go (or C).

Comment: Could you explain where this string comes from ? for example: is it in a json payload ?

Comment: my original string are converted from []bytes. Those bytes are content of response body. I printed out the content of []bytes and it's `[92 117 48 51 48 49]` which is the byte data of `"\\u0301"`

Comment: So, is it a plain text HTTP response, consisting of only 6 characters? (backslash, u, 0, 3, 0, 1)

Comment: not exactly. these characters are part of http response. They are in a json payload.

Comment: If you have the complete json, you don't need to worry about manually un-escaping the byte sequence, because `Unmarshal` will take care of it. [Playground link](https://play.golang.com/p/rINCgKCVhgZ)

Comment: somehow I just don't see any proper struct in previous work. After I created it, `Unmarshal` actually act perfectly. Thank you all for the patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to convert a byte sequence that contains escaped Unicode sequences and control sequences to a Unicode string, then you can use [strconv.Unquote](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#Unquote) function.

To do this, convert the bytes to a string, escape the double-quote and newline characters, and add double-quote characters at the beginning and end of this string.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    b := []byte{65, 92, 117, 48, 51, 48, 49, 9, 88, 10, 34, 65, 34}
    // the same as
    // b := []byte("A\\u0301\tX\n\"A\"")

    // convert to string
    s := string(b)

    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println("=========")

    // escape double quotes
    s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, "\"", "\\\"")
    // escape newlines
    s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, "\n", "\\n")

    r, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + s + `"`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(r)
    fmt.Println("=========")
}
```

Output:

```
A\u0301 X
"A"
=========
Á  X
"A"
=========
```

https://go.dev/play/p/WRsNGOT1zLR

Comment: Thank you for such succinct answer and it solves my problem direclty..